# Function to write an array to an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, arraylist

I am trying to create a VBA function which writes an array to a .NET `System.Collections.ArrayList` and returns it.

So far I have:

```
Function arrayToArrayList(inArray As Variant) As ArrayList
    'function to take input array and output as arraylist

    If IsArray(inArray) Then
        Dim result As New ArrayList
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(inArray) To UBound(inArray)
            result.Add inArray(i) 'throws the error
        Next i
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    Set arrayToArrayList = result
End Function
```

Called with (for example)

```
Sub testArrayListWriter()
    'tests with variant/string array
    'intend to pass array of custom class objects
    Dim result As ArrayList
    Dim myArray As Variant
    myArray = Split("this,will,be,an,array",",")
    Set result = arrayToArrayList(myArray) 
End Sub
```

But I get the error

> Variable uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Presumably because my array is not the correct type (maybe `Variant`). However

```
Dim v As Variant, o As Variant
v = "test_string"
set o = New testClass
result.Add v 'add a string in variant form
result.Add o 'add an object in variant form
```

raises no errors, so the problem isn't directly to do with the `Variant` type

What's going on here, and is there any way of writing an array of unspecified type to the `ArrayList`, or will I have to define the type of `inArray`?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error exactly?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Ah yes, forgot that. Adding to the array list is what raises the error. The error is raised whether I pass an array of `myClass` (`Dim classArray() As myClass`) or any other array (as far as I can tell). But if I explicitly state the type of `inArray` e.g. `Function arrayToArrayList(inArray() As myClass) As ArrayList`, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
result.Add inArray(i)
```

to

```
result.Add CVar(inArray(i))
```

Comment: This is what I was after! Any idea why the extra step is required?

Comment: @Greedo Well, I can't tell you for sure, but I suspect that the reason is in parameter's type. Since `ArrayList` expects `Object`, VBA's `String` somehow doesn't fit this type, so my thought was to convert a value into "chameleon" - i.e. `Variant`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this.  First is late binding if you don't have a reference to `mscorlib.dll`.  You'll see that I've changed your ArrayList to Object for declaring the function and the return value (retVal).  The test sub also declares result as Object.  The retVal and result are both late bound to `System.Collections.ArrayList`.  You also need to declare inArray and myArray as dynamic arrays of string. In your example, Split expects returns an array of strings, so you need provide a declared dynamic array of strings.  If you wanted to other object types, then you'd pass those declared object types to your function.

```
Private Function arrayToArrayList(inArray() As String) As Object
    'function to take input array and output as arraylist
    Dim retVal As Object
    Set retVal = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    If IsArray(inArray) Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(inArray) To UBound(inArray)
            retVal.Add inArray(i)
        Next i
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    Set arrayToArrayList = retVal
End Function

Public Sub testArrayListWriter()
    'tests with variant/string array
    'intend to pass array of custom class objects
    Dim result As Object
    Dim myArray() As String
    Set result = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    myArray = Split("this,will,be,an,array", ",")
    Set result = arrayToArrayList(myArray)
End Sub
```

The second way is to add a reference to mscorlib.dll through the `Tools->Reference` menu item.  When the dialog box appears you'll have to click browse.  You'll need to browse to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and then select the folder with the current version of .NET on your machine.  In that folder you'll find `mscorlib.dll` and `mscorelib.tlb`.  Highlight the file ending in .TLB file, click the Open button, on the Tools Reference dialog, click OK.

Now you can use any of the classes in Systems.Collections directly in your code.  This is called early binding and looks like this

```
Private Function arrayToArrayList(inArray() As String) As ArrayList
    'function to take input array and output as arraylist
    Dim retVal As ArrayList

    If IsArray(inArray) Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(inArray) To UBound(inArray)
            retVal.Add inArray(i)
        Next i
    Else
        Err.Raise 5
    End If

    Set arrayToArrayList = retVal
End Function

Public Sub testArrayListWriter()
    'tests with variant/string array
    'intend to pass array of custom class objects
    Dim result As ArrayList
    Dim myArray() As String

    myArray = Split("this,will,be,an,array", ",")
    Set result = arrayToArrayList(myArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: So was this a test or something.  He gave the obvious answer if you know what you're doing.  I went the extra mile to help someone understand how all this works, but apparently you are just testin us in some attempt to make yourself look superior.  I am shocked and am going to report you to the moderator. Most of us are here trying to help one another and apparently you are not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the assignment of the return value from the Split function to a variable that has not been decalred anywhere.

Try adding:

```
Dim myArray() as string
```

inside the `testArrayListWriter()` procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working; I still get the error being raised when I try to add to the `arrayList`, regardless of how `myArray` is `Dim`med. N.B, I'm not using `Option Explicit` in this test module if that's what you meant